# Chrome becomes unresponsive after window "snap"

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, aero-snap

Chrome occasionally becomes unresponsive after snapping it to the side. The contents fail to resize to the new window size, and Chrome does not respond to any mouse/keyboard input. The work-around is to switch to another application and back again. Is there a better solution?

Although I am still having this problem with Chrome v49, this issue was closed as fixed in v45: [Issue 516234 UI stops updating when multiple Chrome windows are snapped to the left/right in Windows 10](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516234)

Comment: Ive noticed the same behavior on one of my computers.

Answer (score 0):

**Installing any theme seems to prevent this from happening.** Try installing the ['classic' theme](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/classic/hkacjpbfdknhflllbcmjibkdeoafencn) provided by Google to maintain Chrome's look and feel. It looks exactly the same, so I don't know what changed but Chrome stopped freezing for me.

Mentioned in a lot of places, like this Reddit discussion: [Chrome Windows keeps freezing when I use Aero Snap](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/3jmqc7/chrome_windows_keeps_freezing_when_i_use_aero_snap/)

Comment: This theme didn't fix it for me but others did.